# Functional Analysis problem about bounded linear operations

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

Let X and Y be normed spaces non-empty. If every bounded linear operator $T:X \to Y$, non trivial, is surjective, show that dimY = 1.

Can someone help me with that? The clue is to use the Hahn-Banach theorem.